# Accessing a remote API that requires a whitelisted referring domain name via Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I have a general use question before I go down a road that might not be possible. I want to build an app that can interface with an API (read data and update date) on an external website. The external site offers two methods to connect to the API, a client and server set of API calls. The client method requires whitelisting the referring domain and the server method requires whitelisting the IP of the referring site.

If I'm building a regular webpage and want to connect to the API then if HOST.com is the site I want to connect TO and CLIENT.com is the site I want to connect FROM, then I would whitelist CLIENT.com in the setup files of HOST.com.

Alternatively, if I want to access HOST.com via the server API's (like php) then I need to whitelist CLIENT.com's website IP in the setup files of HOST.com.

My question is, is this something that can be done within Cordova? I obviousy won't be able to whitelist an IP of the device, but can the device pass the a referring domain to the HOST.com so it passes the whitelist?

Or am I going to have to setup some kind of webapp hosted in the cloud that the app interfaces with and that hosted app then accesses HOST.com with a whitelisted domain (or even via Server API and a whitelisted IP).

I realize the generality of this question, but would be helpful with any feedback. Want to point out this is NOT about whitelisting on the Cordova app, this is a server configuration on the remote server. If CLIENT.com is not whitelisted then CLIENT.com can NOT access HOST.com Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make anything with simple ajax call. If you have PHP knowledge you can use this to send to another url(for example some data):

**[PHP - called with ajax]**

```
    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'name' => $name,
            'surname' => $surname
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    //call some api
    $result = file_get_contents('http://someurl.com/write.php?key=2q2q3q&name='.$name.'&surname='.$surname.', false, $context);

if($context) {
  echo "success"; // ajax returned
} else {
  echo "error"; // ajax returned
}
```

So after ajax call (updating or something), you can send that data also on other host.com.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is it's the remote server that requires a whitelisted domain. So I don't think accessing the remote server is possible from Cordova directly. But what I've done, and I think you're saying the same thing here, is to create a website (ie a proxy) that has an IP whitelisted on the remote server and setup PHP to access it. Then my Cordova app uses XMLhttp to call that remote PHP that then goes to the remote server and all the data comes back to Cordova.

Comment: yep, thats exactly what I am saying :)